# Several sticky headers in a page

Tags: javascript, html, css, sticky

I have content like the following `JSfiddle` shows:

[My Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4nwjtb5c/40/)

The layout of my page is also similar, where the left half of the page has something else which is not the scope of this question and the right half shows the content as in the JSFiddle above.

I have several `Wrapper` div one after another. Every `Wrapper` div will contain n number of `Details` div with each `Details` div made of 2 div's viz. `Title` and the actual content.

If the number of `Details` div in a `Wrapper` is more than the height of the page, while scrolling down, the `Wrapper Title` becomes hidden.

How do I make the `Wrapper Title` sticky till the end of the `Wrapper`. As soon as a `Wrapper` is crossed, the `Wrapper Title` of next `Wrapper` should become sticky.

Please see: [sticky header](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sticky_header.asp)  to see what I am talking about. I want something similar, but I have several `Wrappers` one after another with different `Wrapper Title` each of which should become sticky in the scope of that `Wrapper`.

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.wrapperTitle {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.detailDiv {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-left: 7px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-right: 2px;
}

.detailTitle {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: pink;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.details {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Wrapper div 1 -->
<div id="wrapperDiv" class="wrapper">
  <div id="wrapperDivTitle" class="wrapperTitle">
    Wrapper Title 1
  </div>
  <!-- detail div 1 -->
  <div id="detailDiv" class="detailDiv">
    <div id="detailDivTitle" class="detailTitle">
      Detail Div
    </div>
    <div id="detailDivDetails" class="details">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tincidunt turpis non tincidunt vestibulum. Nulla porttitor sagittis leo in malesuada. Suspendisse maximus scelerisque est, at semper leo dapibus vel. Nam efficitur dui at libero ultricies, posuere fermentum velit fringilla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur nec nisl sed ligula porta laoreet non at nunc. Mauris laoreet ultrices fermentum. Donec placerat eros vitae egestas vehicula. Etiam at finibus quam, in lacinia mauris. Mauris non ornare massa.
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- detail div 2 -->
  <div id="detailDiv" class="detailDiv">
    <div id="detailDivTitle" class="detailTitle">
      Detail Div
    </div>
    <div id="detailDivDetails" class="details">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tincidunt turpis non tincidunt vestibulum. Nulla porttitor sagittis leo in malesuada. Suspendisse maximus scelerisque est, at semper leo dapibus vel. Nam efficitur dui at libero ultricies, posuere fermentum velit fringilla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur nec nisl sed ligula porta laoreet non at nunc. Mauris laoreet ultrices fermentum. Donec placerat eros vitae egestas vehicula. Etiam at finibus quam, in lacinia mauris. Mauris non ornare massa.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Wrapper div 2 -->
<div id="wrapper_div" class="wrapper">
  <div id="wrapper_div_title" class="wrapperTitle">
    Wrapper Title 2
  </div>
  <!-- detail div 1 -->
  <div id="detailDiv" class="detailDiv">
    <div id="detailDivTitle" class="detailTitle">
      Detail Div
    </div>
    <div id="detailDivDetails" class="details">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tincidunt turpis non tincidunt vestibulum. Nulla porttitor sagittis leo in malesuada. Suspendisse maximus scelerisque est, at semper leo dapibus vel. Nam efficitur dui at libero ultricies, posuere fermentum velit fringilla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur nec nisl sed ligula porta laoreet non at nunc. Mauris laoreet ultrices fermentum. Donec placerat eros vitae egestas vehicula. Etiam at finibus quam, in lacinia mauris. Mauris non ornare massa.
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- detail div 2 -->
  <div id="detailDiv" class="detailDiv">
    <div id="detailDivTitle" class="detailTitle">
      Detail Div
    </div>
    <div id="detailDivDetails" class="details">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tincidunt turpis non tincidunt vestibulum. Nulla porttitor sagittis leo in malesuada. Suspendisse maximus scelerisque est, at semper leo dapibus vel. Nam efficitur dui at libero ultricies, posuere fermentum velit fringilla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur nec nisl sed ligula porta laoreet non at nunc. Mauris laoreet ultrices fermentum. Donec placerat eros vitae egestas vehicula. Etiam at finibus quam, in lacinia mauris. Mauris non ornare massa.
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- detail div 3 -->
  <div id="detailDiv" class="detailDiv">
    <div id="detailDivTitle" class="detailTitle">
      Detail Div
    </div>
    <div id="detailDivDetails" class="details">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tincidunt turpis non tincidunt vestibulum. Nulla porttitor sagittis leo in malesuada. Suspendisse maximus scelerisque est, at semper leo dapibus vel. Nam efficitur dui at libero ultricies, posuere fermentum velit fringilla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur nec nisl sed ligula porta laoreet non at nunc. Mauris laoreet ultrices fermentum. Donec placerat eros vitae egestas vehicula. Etiam at finibus quam, in lacinia mauris. Mauris non ornare massa.
    </div>
  </div>
  
    <!-- detail div 4 -->
  <div id="detailDiv" class="detailDiv">
    <div id="detailDivTitle" class="detailTitle">
      Detail Div
    </div>
    <div id="detailDivDetails" class="details">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tincidunt turpis non tincidunt vestibulum. Nulla porttitor sagittis leo in malesuada. Suspendisse maximus scelerisque est, at semper leo dapibus vel. Nam efficitur dui at libero ultricies, posuere fermentum velit fringilla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur nec nisl sed ligula porta laoreet non at nunc. Mauris laoreet ultrices fermentum. Donec placerat eros vitae egestas vehicula. Etiam at finibus quam, in lacinia mauris. Mauris non ornare massa.
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- detail div 5 -->
  <div id="detailDiv" class="detailDiv">
    <div id="detailDivTitle" class="detailTitle">
      Detail Div
    </div>
    <div id="detailDivDetails" class="details">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tincidunt turpis non tincidunt vestibulum. Nulla porttitor sagittis leo in malesuada. Suspendisse maximus scelerisque est, at semper leo dapibus vel. Nam efficitur dui at libero ultricies, posuere fermentum velit fringilla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur nec nisl sed ligula porta laoreet non at nunc. Mauris laoreet ultrices fermentum. Donec placerat eros vitae egestas vehicula. Etiam at finibus quam, in lacinia mauris. Mauris non ornare massa.
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- detail div 6 -->
  <div id="detailDiv" class="detailDiv">
    <div id="detailDivTitle" class="detailTitle">
      Detail Div
    </div>
    <div id="detailDivDetails" class="details">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tincidunt turpis non tincidunt vestibulum. Nulla porttitor sagittis leo in malesuada. Suspendisse maximus scelerisque est, at semper leo dapibus vel. Nam efficitur dui at libero ultricies, posuere fermentum velit fringilla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur nec nisl sed ligula porta laoreet non at nunc. Mauris laoreet ultrices fermentum. Donec placerat eros vitae egestas vehicula. Etiam at finibus quam, in lacinia mauris. Mauris non ornare massa.
    </div>
  </div>
  
    <!-- detail div 7 -->
  <div id="detailDiv" class="detailDiv">
    <div id="detailDivTitle" class="detailTitle">
      Detail Div
    </div>
    <div id="detailDivDetails" class="details">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tincidunt turpis non tincidunt vestibulum. Nulla porttitor sagittis leo in malesuada. Suspendisse maximus scelerisque est, at semper leo dapibus vel. Nam efficitur dui at libero ultricies, posuere fermentum velit fringilla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur nec nisl sed ligula porta laoreet non at nunc. Mauris laoreet ultrices fermentum. Donec placerat eros vitae egestas vehicula. Etiam at finibus quam, in lacinia mauris. Mauris non ornare massa.
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- detail div 8 -->
  <div id="detailDiv" class="detailDiv">
    <div id="detailDivTitle" class="detailTitle">
      Detail Div
    </div>
    <div id="detailDivDetails" class="details">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tincidunt turpis non tincidunt vestibulum. Nulla porttitor sagittis leo in malesuada. Suspendisse maximus scelerisque est, at semper leo dapibus vel. Nam efficitur dui at libero ultricies, posuere fermentum velit fringilla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur nec nisl sed ligula porta laoreet non at nunc. Mauris laoreet ultrices fermentum. Donec placerat eros vitae egestas vehicula. Etiam at finibus quam, in lacinia mauris. Mauris non ornare massa.
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- detail div 9 -->
  <div id="detailDiv" class="detailDiv">
    <div id="detailDivTitle" class="detailTitle">
      Detail Div
    </div>
    <div id="detailDivDetails" class="details">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tincidunt turpis non tincidunt vestibulum. Nulla porttitor sagittis leo in malesuada. Suspendisse maximus scelerisque est, at semper leo dapibus vel. Nam efficitur dui at libero ultricies, posuere fermentum velit fringilla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur nec nisl sed ligula porta laoreet non at nunc. Mauris laoreet ultrices fermentum. Donec placerat eros vitae egestas vehicula. Etiam at finibus quam, in lacinia mauris. Mauris non ornare massa.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Wrapper div 3 -->
<div id="wrapper_div" class="wrapper">
  <div id="wrapper_div_title" class="wrapperTitle">
    Wrapper Title 3
  </div>
  <!-- detail div 1 -->
  <div id="detailDiv" class="detailDiv">
    <div id="detailDivTitle" class="detailTitle">
      Detail Div
    </div>
    <div id="detailDivDetails" class="details">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tincidunt turpis non tincidunt vestibulum. Nulla porttitor sagittis leo in malesuada. Suspendisse maximus scelerisque est, at semper leo dapibus vel. Nam efficitur dui at libero ultricies, posuere fermentum velit fringilla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur nec nisl sed ligula porta laoreet non at nunc. Mauris laoreet ultrices fermentum. Donec placerat eros vitae egestas vehicula. Etiam at finibus quam, in lacinia mauris. Mauris non ornare massa.
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- detail div 2 -->
  <div id="detailDiv" class="detailDiv">
    <div id="detailDivTitle" class="detailTitle">
      Detail Div
    </div>
    <div id="detailDivDetails" class="details">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tincidunt turpis non tincidunt vestibulum. Nulla porttitor sagittis leo in malesuada. Suspendisse maximus scelerisque est, at semper leo dapibus vel. Nam efficitur dui at libero ultricies, posuere fermentum velit fringilla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur nec nisl sed ligula porta laoreet non at nunc. Mauris laoreet ultrices fermentum. Donec placerat eros vitae egestas vehicula. Etiam at finibus quam, in lacinia mauris. Mauris non ornare massa.
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- detail div 3 -->
  <div id="detailDiv" class="detailDiv">
    <div id="detailDivTitle" class="detailTitle">
      Detail Div
    </div>
    <div id="detailDivDetails" class="details">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tincidunt turpis non tincidunt vestibulum. Nulla porttitor sagittis leo in malesuada. Suspendisse maximus scelerisque est, at semper leo dapibus vel. Nam efficitur dui at libero ultricies, posuere fermentum velit fringilla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur nec nisl sed ligula porta laoreet non at nunc. Mauris laoreet ultrices fermentum. Donec placerat eros vitae egestas vehicula. Etiam at finibus quam, in lacinia mauris. Mauris non ornare massa.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Wrapper div 4 -->
<div id="wrapper_div" class="wrapper">
  <div id="wrapper_div_title" class="wrapperTitle">
    Wrapper Title 4
  </div>
  <!-- detail div 1 -->
  <div id="detailDiv" class="detailDiv">
    <div id="detailDivTitle" class="detailTitle">
      Detail Div
    </div>
    <div id="detailDivDetails" class="details">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tincidunt turpis non tincidunt vestibulum. Nulla porttitor sagittis leo in malesuada. Suspendisse maximus scelerisque est, at semper leo dapibus vel. Nam efficitur dui at libero ultricies, posuere fermentum velit fringilla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur nec nisl sed ligula porta laoreet non at nunc. Mauris laoreet ultrices fermentum. Donec placerat eros vitae egestas vehicula. Etiam at finibus quam, in lacinia mauris. Mauris non ornare massa.
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- detail div 2 -->
  <div id="detailDiv" class="detailDiv">
    <div id="detailDivTitle" class="detailTitle">
      Detail Div
    </div>
    <div id="detailDivDetails" class="details">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tincidunt turpis non tincidunt vestibulum. Nulla porttitor sagittis leo in malesuada. Suspendisse maximus scelerisque est, at semper leo dapibus vel. Nam efficitur dui at libero ultricies, posuere fermentum velit fringilla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur nec nisl sed ligula porta laoreet non at nunc. Mauris laoreet ultrices fermentum. Donec placerat eros vitae egestas vehicula. Etiam at finibus quam, in lacinia mauris. Mauris non ornare massa.
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- detail div 3 -->
  <div id="detailDiv" class="detailDiv">
    <div id="detailDivTitle" class="detailTitle">
      Detail Div
    </div>
    <div id="detailDivDetails" class="details">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tincidunt turpis non tincidunt vestibulum. Nulla porttitor sagittis leo in malesuada. Suspendisse maximus scelerisque est, at semper leo dapibus vel. Nam efficitur dui at libero ultricies, posuere fermentum velit fringilla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur nec nisl sed ligula porta laoreet non at nunc. Mauris laoreet ultrices fermentum. Donec placerat eros vitae egestas vehicula. Etiam at finibus quam, in lacinia mauris. Mauris non ornare massa.
    </div>
  </div>
  
    <!-- detail div 4 -->
  <div id="detailDiv" class="detailDiv">
    <div id="detailDivTitle" class="detailTitle">
      Detail Div
    </div>
    <div id="detailDivDetails" class="details">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tincidunt turpis non tincidunt vestibulum. Nulla porttitor sagittis leo in malesuada. Suspendisse maximus scelerisque est, at semper leo dapibus vel. Nam efficitur dui at libero ultricies, posuere fermentum velit fringilla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur nec nisl sed ligula porta laoreet non at nunc. Mauris laoreet ultrices fermentum. Donec placerat eros vitae egestas vehicula. Etiam at finibus quam, in lacinia mauris. Mauris non ornare massa.
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- detail div 5 -->
  <div id="detailDiv" class="detailDiv">
    <div id="detailDivTitle" class="detailTitle">
      Detail Div
    </div>
    <div id="detailDivDetails" class="details">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tincidunt turpis non tincidunt vestibulum. Nulla porttitor sagittis leo in malesuada. Suspendisse maximus scelerisque est, at semper leo dapibus vel. Nam efficitur dui at libero ultricies, posuere fermentum velit fringilla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur nec nisl sed ligula porta laoreet non at nunc. Mauris laoreet ultrices fermentum. Donec placerat eros vitae egestas vehicula. Etiam at finibus quam, in lacinia mauris. Mauris non ornare massa.
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- detail div 6 -->
  <div id="detailDiv" class="detailDiv">
    <div id="detailDivTitle" class="detailTitle">
      Detail Div
    </div>
    <div id="detailDivDetails" class="details">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tincidunt turpis non tincidunt vestibulum. Nulla porttitor sagittis leo in malesuada. Suspendisse maximus scelerisque est, at semper leo dapibus vel. Nam efficitur dui at libero ultricies, posuere fermentum velit fringilla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur nec nisl sed ligula porta laoreet non at nunc. Mauris laoreet ultrices fermentum. Donec placerat eros vitae egestas vehicula. Etiam at finibus quam, in lacinia mauris. Mauris non ornare massa.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Wrapper div 5 -->
<div id="wrapper_div" class="wrapper">
  <div id="wrapper_div_title" class="wrapperTitle">
    Wrapper Title 5
  </div>
  <!-- detail div 1 -->
  <div id="detailDiv" class="detailDiv">
    <div id="detailDivTitle" class="detailTitle">
      Detail Div
    </div>
    <div id="detailDivDetails" class="details">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tincidunt turpis non tincidunt vestibulum. Nulla porttitor sagittis leo in malesuada. Suspendisse maximus scelerisque est, at semper leo dapibus vel. Nam efficitur dui at libero ultricies, posuere fermentum velit fringilla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur nec nisl sed ligula porta laoreet non at nunc. Mauris laoreet ultrices fermentum. Donec placerat eros vitae egestas vehicula. Etiam at finibus quam, in lacinia mauris. Mauris non ornare massa.
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- detail div 2 -->
  <div id="detailDiv" class="detailDiv">
    <div id="detailDivTitle" class="detailTitle">
      Detail Div
    </div>
    <div id="detailDivDetails" class="details">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tincidunt turpis non tincidunt vestibulum. Nulla porttitor sagittis leo in malesuada. Suspendisse maximus scelerisque est, at semper leo dapibus vel. Nam efficitur dui at libero ultricies, posuere fermentum velit fringilla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur nec nisl sed ligula porta laoreet non at nunc. Mauris laoreet ultrices fermentum. Donec placerat eros vitae egestas vehicula. Etiam at finibus quam, in lacinia mauris. Mauris non ornare massa.
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- detail div 3 -->
  <div id="detailDiv" class="detailDiv">
    <div id="detailDivTitle" class="detailTitle">
      Detail Div
    </div>
    <div id="detailDivDetails" class="details">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tincidunt turpis non tincidunt vestibulum. Nulla porttitor sagittis leo in malesuada. Suspendisse maximus scelerisque est, at semper leo dapibus vel. Nam efficitur dui at libero ultricies, posuere fermentum velit fringilla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur nec nisl sed ligula porta laoreet non at nunc. Mauris laoreet ultrices fermentum. Donec placerat eros vitae egestas vehicula. Etiam at finibus quam, in lacinia mauris. Mauris non ornare massa.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you set a height to `detailDiv` if the height of this div exceeds a certain height, and `overflow: auto`. This way `wrapperTitle` will be fixed all the times. Although in this case there will be two vertical scrollbars.

Comment: Used this Plugin attached url - https://emn178.github.io/jquery-stickit/samples/stack/

Comment: Here's an codepen example: https://codepen.io/chrissp26/pen/gBrdo

Answer (score 2):

Add position sticky on `wrapperTitle`

```
.wrapperTitle {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/87ub1c4m/7/

Comment: does this work in IE as well? I am looking for a solution which works on IE, Edge, Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

Comment: @Vicky It won't work in IE, since `position: sticky` is not supported. See https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky

Answer (score 0):

I've adapted the example from your [link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sticky_header.asp) for your issue.

1. Add unique **id** for each **title**:

   ```
   <div id="wrapperDivTitle1" class="wrapperTitle">
       Wrapper Title 1
   </div>
   ```
2. Add **.sticky** class:

   ```
   .sticky {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
   }
   ```
3. JS code:

   ```
   window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

   var headers = [1,2,3,4,5].map(i => {        
       let element = document.getElementById("wrapperDivTitle" + i);     
       return {
           element: element,
           sticky: element.offsetTop
       }
   });

   function myFunction() {
        headers.forEach(item => {
            if (window.pageYOffset > item.sticky) {
                item.element.classList.add("sticky");
            } else { 
                item.element.classList.remove("sticky");
            }
        });
   }
   ```

Snippet

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var headers = [1,2,3,4,5].map(i => {
 
 let element = document.getElementById("wrapperDivTitle" + i);

 return {
  element: element,
  sticky: element.offsetTop
 }
});

function myFunction() {
 headers.forEach(item => {
  if (window.pageYOffset > item.sticky) {
    item.element.classList.add("sticky");
   } else { 
           item.element.classList.remove("sticky");
   }
 });      
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.wrapperTitle {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.detailDiv {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-left: 7px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-right: 2px;
}

.detailTitle {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: pink;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.details {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Wrapper div 1 -->
<div id="wrapperDiv" class="wrapper">
  <div id="wrapperDivTitle1" class="wrapperTitle">
    Wrapper Title 1
  </div>
  <!-- detail div 1 -->
  <div id="detailDiv" class="detailDiv">
    <div id="detailDivTitle" class="detailTitle">
      Detail Div
    </div>
    <div id="detailDivDetails" class="details">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tincidunt turpis non tincidunt vestibulum. Nulla porttitor sagittis leo in malesuada. Suspendisse maximus scelerisque est, at semper leo dapibus vel. Nam efficitur dui at libero ultricies, posuere fermentum velit fringilla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur nec nisl sed ligula porta laoreet non at nunc. Mauris laoreet ultrices fermentum. Donec placerat eros vitae egestas vehicula. Etiam at finibus quam, in lacinia mauris. Mauris non ornare massa.
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- detail div 2 -->
  <div id="detailDiv" class="detailDiv">
    <div id="detailDivTitle" class="detailTitle">
      Detail Div
    </div>
    <div id="detailDivDetails" class="details">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tincidunt turpis non tincidunt vestibulum. Nulla porttitor sagittis leo in malesuada. Suspendisse maximus scelerisque est, at semper leo dapibus vel. Nam efficitur dui at libero ultricies, posuere fermentum velit fringilla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur nec nisl sed ligula porta laoreet non at nunc. Mauris laoreet ultrices fermentum. Donec placerat eros vitae egestas vehicula. Etiam at finibus quam, in lacinia mauris. Mauris non ornare massa.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Wrapper div 2 -->
<div id="wrapper_div" class="wrapper">
  <div id="wrapperDivTitle2" class="wrapperTitle">
    Wrapper Title 2
  </div>
  <!-- detail div 1 -->
  <div id="detailDiv" class="detailDiv">
    <div id="detailDivTitle" class="detailTitle">
      Detail Div
    </div>
    <div id="detailDivDetails" class="details">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tincidunt turpis non tincidunt vestibulum. Nulla porttitor sagittis leo in malesuada. Suspendisse maximus scelerisque est, at semper leo dapibus vel. Nam efficitur dui at libero ultricies, posuere fermentum velit fringilla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur nec nisl sed ligula porta laoreet non at nunc. Mauris laoreet ultrices fermentum. Donec placerat eros vitae egestas vehicula. Etiam at finibus quam, in lacinia mauris. Mauris non ornare massa.
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- detail div 2 -->
  <div id="detailDiv" class="detailDiv">
    <div id="detailDivTitle" class="detailTitle">
      Detail Div
    </div>
    <div id="detailDivDetails" class="details">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tincidunt turpis non tincidunt vestibulum. Nulla porttitor sagittis leo in malesuada. Suspendisse maximus scelerisque est, at semper leo dapibus vel. Nam efficitur dui at libero ultricies, posuere fermentum velit fringilla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur nec nisl sed ligula porta laoreet non at nunc. Mauris laoreet ultrices fermentum. Donec placerat eros vitae egestas vehicula. Etiam at finibus quam, in lacinia mauris. Mauris non ornare massa.
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- detail div 3 -->
  <div id="detailDiv" class="detailDiv">
    <div id="detailDivTitle" class="detailTitle">
      Detail Div
    </div>
    <div id="detailDivDetails" class="details">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tincidunt turpis non tincidunt vestibulum. Nulla porttitor sagittis leo in malesuada. Suspendisse maximus scelerisque est, at semper leo dapibus vel. Nam efficitur dui at libero ultricies, posuere fermentum velit fringilla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur nec nisl sed ligula porta laoreet non at nunc. Mauris laoreet ultrices fermentum. Donec placerat eros vitae egestas vehicula. Etiam at finibus quam, in lacinia mauris. Mauris non ornare massa.
    </div>
  </div>
  
    <!-- detail div 4 -->
  <div id="detailDiv" class="detailDiv">
    <div id="detailDivTitle" class="detailTitle">
      Detail Div
    </div>
    <div id="detailDivDetails" class="details">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tincidunt turpis non tincidunt vestibulum. Nulla porttitor sagittis leo in malesuada. Suspendisse maximus scelerisque est, at semper leo dapibus vel. Nam efficitur dui at libero ultricies, posuere fermentum velit fringilla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur nec nisl sed ligula porta laoreet non at nunc. Mauris laoreet ultrices fermentum. Donec placerat eros vitae egestas vehicula. Etiam at finibus quam, in lacinia mauris. Mauris non ornare massa.
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- detail div 5 -->
  <div id="detailDiv" class="detailDiv">
    <div id="detailDivTitle" class="detailTitle">
      Detail Div
    </div>
    <div id="detailDivDetails" class="details">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tincidunt turpis non tincidunt vestibulum. Nulla porttitor sagittis leo in malesuada. Suspendisse maximus scelerisque est, at semper leo dapibus vel. Nam efficitur dui at libero ultricies, posuere fermentum velit fringilla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur nec nisl sed ligula porta laoreet non at nunc. Mauris laoreet ultrices fermentum. Donec placerat eros vitae egestas vehicula. Etiam at finibus quam, in lacinia mauris. Mauris non ornare massa.
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- detail div 6 -->
  <div id="detailDiv" class="detailDiv">
    <div id="detailDivTitle" class="detailTitle">
      Detail Div
    </div>
    <div id="detailDivDetails" class="details">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tincidunt turpis non tincidunt vestibulum. Nulla porttitor sagittis leo in malesuada. Suspendisse maximus scelerisque est, at semper leo dapibus vel. Nam efficitur dui at libero ultricies, posuere fermentum velit fringilla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur nec nisl sed ligula porta laoreet non at nunc. Mauris laoreet ultrices fermentum. Donec placerat eros vitae egestas vehicula. Etiam at finibus quam, in lacinia mauris. Mauris non ornare massa.
    </div>
  </div>
  
    <!-- detail div 7 -->
  <div id="detailDiv" class="detailDiv">
    <div id="detailDivTitle" class="detailTitle">
      Detail Div
    </div>
    <div id="detailDivDetails" class="details">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tincidunt turpis non tincidunt vestibulum. Nulla porttitor sagittis leo in malesuada. Suspendisse maximus scelerisque est, at semper leo dapibus vel. Nam efficitur dui at libero ultricies, posuere fermentum velit fringilla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur nec nisl sed ligula porta laoreet non at nunc. Mauris laoreet ultrices fermentum. Donec placerat eros vitae egestas vehicula. Etiam at finibus quam, in lacinia mauris. Mauris non ornare massa.
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- detail div 8 -->
  <div id="detailDiv" class="detailDiv">
    <div id="detailDivTitle" class="detailTitle">
      Detail Div
    </div>
    <div id="detailDivDetails" class="details">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tincidunt turpis non tincidunt vestibulum. Nulla porttitor sagittis leo in malesuada. Suspendisse maximus scelerisque est, at semper leo dapibus vel. Nam efficitur dui at libero ultricies, posuere fermentum velit fringilla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur nec nisl sed ligula porta laoreet non at nunc. Mauris laoreet ultrices fermentum. Donec placerat eros vitae egestas vehicula. Etiam at finibus quam, in lacinia mauris. Mauris non ornare massa.
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- detail div 9 -->
  <div id="detailDiv" class="detailDiv">
    <div id="detailDivTitle" class="detailTitle">
      Detail Div
    </div>
    <div id="detailDivDetails" class="details">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tincidunt turpis non tincidunt vestibulum. Nulla porttitor sagittis leo in malesuada. Suspendisse maximus scelerisque est, at semper leo dapibus vel. Nam efficitur dui at libero ultricies, posuere fermentum velit fringilla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur nec nisl sed ligula porta laoreet non at nunc. Mauris laoreet ultrices fermentum. Donec placerat eros vitae egestas vehicula. Etiam at finibus quam, in lacinia mauris. Mauris non ornare massa.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Wrapper div 3 -->
<div id="wrapper_div" class="wrapper">
  <div id="wrapperDivTitle3" class="wrapperTitle">
    Wrapper Title 3
  </div>
  <!-- detail div 1 -->
  <div id="detailDiv" class="detailDiv">
    <div id="detailDivTitle" class="detailTitle">
      Detail Div
    </div>
    <div id="detailDivDetails" class="details">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tincidunt turpis non tincidunt vestibulum. Nulla porttitor sagittis leo in malesuada. Suspendisse maximus scelerisque est, at semper leo dapibus vel. Nam efficitur dui at libero ultricies, posuere fermentum velit fringilla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur nec nisl sed ligula porta laoreet non at nunc. Mauris laoreet ultrices fermentum. Donec placerat eros vitae egestas vehicula. Etiam at finibus quam, in lacinia mauris. Mauris non ornare massa.
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- detail div 2 -->
  <div id="detailDiv" class="detailDiv">
    <div id="detailDivTitle" class="detailTitle">
      Detail Div
    </div>
    <div id="detailDivDetails" class="details">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tincidunt turpis non tincidunt vestibulum. Nulla porttitor sagittis leo in malesuada. Suspendisse maximus scelerisque est, at semper leo dapibus vel. Nam efficitur dui at libero ultricies, posuere fermentum velit fringilla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur nec nisl sed ligula porta laoreet non at nunc. Mauris laoreet ultrices fermentum. Donec placerat eros vitae egestas vehicula. Etiam at finibus quam, in lacinia mauris. Mauris non ornare massa.
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- detail div 3 -->
  <div id="detailDiv" class="detailDiv">
    <div id="detailDivTitle" class="detailTitle">
      Detail Div
    </div>
    <div id="detailDivDetails" class="details">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tincidunt turpis non tincidunt vestibulum. Nulla porttitor sagittis leo in malesuada. Suspendisse maximus scelerisque est, at semper leo dapibus vel. Nam efficitur dui at libero ultricies, posuere fermentum velit fringilla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur nec nisl sed ligula porta laoreet non at nunc. Mauris laoreet ultrices fermentum. Donec placerat eros vitae egestas vehicula. Etiam at finibus quam, in lacinia mauris. Mauris non ornare massa.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Wrapper div 4 -->
<div id="wrapper_div" class="wrapper">
  <div id="wrapperDivTitle4" class="wrapperTitle">
    Wrapper Title 4
  </div>
  <!-- detail div 1 -->
  <div id="detailDiv" class="detailDiv">
    <div id="detailDivTitle" class="detailTitle">
      Detail Div
    </div>
    <div id="detailDivDetails" class="details">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tincidunt turpis non tincidunt vestibulum. Nulla porttitor sagittis leo in malesuada. Suspendisse maximus scelerisque est, at semper leo dapibus vel. Nam efficitur dui at libero ultricies, posuere fermentum velit fringilla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur nec nisl sed ligula porta laoreet non at nunc. Mauris laoreet ultrices fermentum. Donec placerat eros vitae egestas vehicula. Etiam at finibus quam, in lacinia mauris. Mauris non ornare massa.
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- detail div 2 -->
  <div id="detailDiv" class="detailDiv">
    <div id="detailDivTitle" class="detailTitle">
      Detail Div
    </div>
    <div id="detailDivDetails" class="details">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tincidunt turpis non tincidunt vestibulum. Nulla porttitor sagittis leo in malesuada. Suspendisse maximus scelerisque est, at semper leo dapibus vel. Nam efficitur dui at libero ultricies, posuere fermentum velit fringilla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur nec nisl sed ligula porta laoreet non at nunc. Mauris laoreet ultrices fermentum. Donec placerat eros vitae egestas vehicula. Etiam at finibus quam, in lacinia mauris. Mauris non ornare massa.
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- detail div 3 -->
  <div id="detailDiv" class="detailDiv">
    <div id="detailDivTitle" class="detailTitle">
      Detail Div
    </div>
    <div id="detailDivDetails" class="details">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tincidunt turpis non tincidunt vestibulum. Nulla porttitor sagittis leo in malesuada. Suspendisse maximus scelerisque est, at semper leo dapibus vel. Nam efficitur dui at libero ultricies, posuere fermentum velit fringilla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur nec nisl sed ligula porta laoreet non at nunc. Mauris laoreet ultrices fermentum. Donec placerat eros vitae egestas vehicula. Etiam at finibus quam, in lacinia mauris. Mauris non ornare massa.
    </div>
  </div>
  
    <!-- detail div 4 -->
  <div id="detailDiv" class="detailDiv">
    <div id="detailDivTitle" class="detailTitle">
      Detail Div
    </div>
    <div id="detailDivDetails" class="details">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tincidunt turpis non tincidunt vestibulum. Nulla porttitor sagittis leo in malesuada. Suspendisse maximus scelerisque est, at semper leo dapibus vel. Nam efficitur dui at libero ultricies, posuere fermentum velit fringilla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur nec nisl sed ligula porta laoreet non at nunc. Mauris laoreet ultrices fermentum. Donec placerat eros vitae egestas vehicula. Etiam at finibus quam, in lacinia mauris. Mauris non ornare massa.
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- detail div 5 -->
  <div id="detailDiv" class="detailDiv">
    <div id="detailDivTitle" class="detailTitle">
      Detail Div
    </div>
    <div id="detailDivDetails" class="details">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tincidunt turpis non tincidunt vestibulum. Nulla porttitor sagittis leo in malesuada. Suspendisse maximus scelerisque est, at semper leo dapibus vel. Nam efficitur dui at libero ultricies, posuere fermentum velit fringilla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur nec nisl sed ligula porta laoreet non at nunc. Mauris laoreet ultrices fermentum. Donec placerat eros vitae egestas vehicula. Etiam at finibus quam, in lacinia mauris. Mauris non ornare massa.
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- detail div 6 -->
  <div id="detailDiv" class="detailDiv">
    <div id="detailDivTitle" class="detailTitle">
      Detail Div
    </div>
    <div id="detailDivDetails" class="details">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tincidunt turpis non tincidunt vestibulum. Nulla porttitor sagittis leo in malesuada. Suspendisse maximus scelerisque est, at semper leo dapibus vel. Nam efficitur dui at libero ultricies, posuere fermentum velit fringilla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur nec nisl sed ligula porta laoreet non at nunc. Mauris laoreet ultrices fermentum. Donec placerat eros vitae egestas vehicula. Etiam at finibus quam, in lacinia mauris. Mauris non ornare massa.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Wrapper div 5 -->
<div id="wrapper_div" class="wrapper">
  <div id="wrapperDivTitle5" class="wrapperTitle">
    Wrapper Title 5
  </div>
  <!-- detail div 1 -->
  <div id="detailDiv" class="detailDiv">
    <div id="detailDivTitle" class="detailTitle">
      Detail Div
    </div>
    <div id="detailDivDetails" class="details">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tincidunt turpis non tincidunt vestibulum. Nulla porttitor sagittis leo in malesuada. Suspendisse maximus scelerisque est, at semper leo dapibus vel. Nam efficitur dui at libero ultricies, posuere fermentum velit fringilla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur nec nisl sed ligula porta laoreet non at nunc. Mauris laoreet ultrices fermentum. Donec placerat eros vitae egestas vehicula. Etiam at finibus quam, in lacinia mauris. Mauris non ornare massa.
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- detail div 2 -->
  <div id="detailDiv" class="detailDiv">
    <div id="detailDivTitle" class="detailTitle">
      Detail Div
    </div>
    <div id="detailDivDetails" class="details">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tincidunt turpis non tincidunt vestibulum. Nulla porttitor sagittis leo in malesuada. Suspendisse maximus scelerisque est, at semper leo dapibus vel. Nam efficitur dui at libero ultricies, posuere fermentum velit fringilla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur nec nisl sed ligula porta laoreet non at nunc. Mauris laoreet ultrices fermentum. Donec placerat eros vitae egestas vehicula. Etiam at finibus quam, in lacinia mauris. Mauris non ornare massa.
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- detail div 3 -->
  <div id="detailDiv" class="detailDiv">
    <div id="detailDivTitle" class="detailTitle">
      Detail Div
    </div>
    <div id="detailDivDetails" class="details">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tincidunt turpis non tincidunt vestibulum. Nulla porttitor sagittis leo in malesuada. Suspendisse maximus scelerisque est, at semper leo dapibus vel. Nam efficitur dui at libero ultricies, posuere fermentum velit fringilla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur nec nisl sed ligula porta laoreet non at nunc. Mauris laoreet ultrices fermentum. Donec placerat eros vitae egestas vehicula. Etiam at finibus quam, in lacinia mauris. Mauris non ornare massa.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems this will work on all browsers. Let me give it a try!